# New xampp version installation

Tags: installation, xampp, new-operator

I was working on xampp version (xampp-win32-1.7.7-VC9-installer.exe).
But now i had installed latest version (xampp-windows-x64-7.4.2-0-VC15-installer.exe).

I copied my project folder into htdocs folder and import my database into phpmyadmin. Database tables imported fine but my project is not working means when i try to open the home page it display nothing but only 2-3 lines of code.

please guide if i need to change anywhere else in xampp or in my project folder.

Thanks and Regards
Himanshoo

Comment: Do any pages work?  Do simple HTML pages work?  Does a phpinfo() page work? What are the "2-3 lines of code?"  You need to give more information.

Comment: nothing work. it displays first 2 3 lines of code of home page. what i did is i change my opening php tag to <?php from earlier <?. this works and all the files working displaying image text everything after that.

Comment: If nothing works (even simple HTML pages with no PHP), then it sounds like something didn't get installed properly.  Uninstall and reinstall and see if it works.

Comment: it works now as i told in my earlier comment. installation was fine. i just change opening tags of php to <?php. it works new and old files working good. is it matter writing <? or <?php